# MYSQL - returning complete set of tags aftering filtering on specific tags

Tags: mysql, select, join, filter, tags

I have normalised a quotations TABLE and i have 4 separate tables pertaining to quotes, authors, quotetags (tags that classify the quotations) and quotestotags (a quotation can have multiple tags e.g. love, happiness, death, etc) it is about 70,000 quotations.

The quotes table consists of the fields id, quotation and authorid
The author table consists of the fields id and author (name of author)
The quotetags consists of the fields id and description (e.g. 1 -> Happiness, 2 -> Admiration)
The quotestotags consists of id, quoteid, tagid foreign keys to the quotes table and the quotetags table eg (1,1,3 ... 2,1,6....3,2,17..etc)

I want to filter the quotations by a series of tags..so if i select Happiness, Love, Relationships i want to select the quotations that have at least one of these tags associated with it (alongside the id, quotation and author).

Now, when i filter the tags, i want to return a GROUP_CONCAT() of ALL THE TAGS for each of the selected quotations NOT just the ones that the user wants to filter by...so if one quotation contains 5 tags and one of them is Happiness, i want the GROUP_CONCAT() to contain all the 5 tags that are associated with it, not just the ones s/he filtered by.

This is my problem.I have got it to work where it seems to return the appropriate quotations but i cant get it to list ALL the associated tags. At the moment it just lists the tags filtered by :( I presume somewhere i need an EXISTS clause.

SO far i have this.

```
 SELECT q.*, (SELECT author FROM authors WHERE authors.id = q.authorid) as 
 authorid, GROUP_CONCAT(qt.description ) as tags
   FROM  quotes AS q
   LEFT JOIN quotestotags AS qtt ON q.id = qtt.quoteid
   LEFT JOIN quotetags AS qt ON qtt.tagid = qt.id
WHERE qt.id IN (40,45,70) // arbitrary list of tagids
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.id ASC
LIMIT 60, 20
```

I just do not know how to get it to list ALL the tags :(

Can someone please help me and point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Also i would appreciate it if someone could show me how i could filter out the quotations that contained ALL the tags passed as a filter (the idea being to return ALL the associated tags to each quotation). So if Happiness AND love were chosen then only those quotations where it was tagged with BOTH Happinesss and LOVE would be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving out the author id (which doesn't seem important for the question):

```
SELECT q.*, GROUP_CONCAT(qt.description ) as tags
FROM quotes q LEFT JOIN
     quotestotags qtt
     ON q.id = qtt.quoteid LEFT JOIN
     quotetags qt
      ON qtt.tagid = qt.id
GROUP BY q.id
HAVING SUM(qt.id IN (40, 45, 70)) > 0
ORDER BY q.id ASC
LIMIT 60, 20
```

The idea is to use a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause to filter the tags.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your prompt reply....However it seems to be timing out after 30 seconds :( so cannot really test it...

Comment: maybe i need to create some indexes to accelerate the search? there are about  70,000 quotations and abot 75000 records in the quotestotags

Comment: On that volume of data, it shouldn't take 30 seconds.  You do need indexes on `quotestotags(quoteid, tagid)`.  I assume the `id` columns have indexes already (by being primary keys).

Comment: yeah...they are primary keyed...well it took longer than 30 secs...how long should CREATE INDEX take for a table with circa 75000 records Gordon pls? ...i started indexing of quoteid tagid and it has taken over 8 mins :(

Comment: I am using WorkBench

Comment: @AlexAinsworth . . . Something is wrong with your system or perhaps 70,000 is really 70,000,000.

Comment: lol Gordon no not 7000000 :) it is a localhost setup....i have noticed it is very slow :( (my laptop isn't  must be some configuration :(  but only on these particularly large tables do you know what could be slowing it up?

Comment: still running after 14 mins doing CREATE_INDEX on qoteid and tagid...thats not right is it?

Comment: @AlexAinsworth . . . Something is seriously wrong with your system.